# Pass Every Line of Input as stdin for Invocation of Utility

Tags: xpath, parallel-processing, gnu, xargs

I have a file containing valid xmls (one per line) and I want to execute a utility (xpath) on each line one by one.

I  tried xargs but that seems doesn't seem to have an option to pass the line as stdin :-

```
% cat <xmls-file> | xargs -p -t -L1 xpath -p "//Path/to/node"

Cannot open file '//Path/to/node' at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/XML/XPath.pm line 53.
```

I also tried parallel --spreadstdin but that doesn't seem to work either :-

```
% cat <xmls-file> | parallel --spreadstdin  xpath -p "//Path/to/node"
junk after document element at line 2, column 0, byte 1607
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want every line of a file to be split off and made stdin for a utility

you could use a for loop in bash shell:

```
cat xmls-file | while read line
do ( echo $f > /tmp/input$$; 
     xpath -p "//Path/to/node" </tmp/input$$
     rm -f /tmp/input$$
);
done
```

The $$ appends the process id number, creating a unique name

I assume xmls-file contains, on each line, what you want iterated into `$f` and that you want this as stdin for a command line, not as a parameter to the command.

On the other hand, your specification may be incorrect and maybe instead you need each line
to be part of a command.  In that case, delete the echo and rm lines, and change the xpath command to include $f wherever the line from the file is needed.

I've not done much XML so the do command may need to be edited.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be close however the loop seems to split my xmls-file on spaces instead of newline. Anything I miss?

Comment: Now that I think of it, that might be a problem.  Is normally used with lists of file names, space separated.

Comment: You could (double quote, I think) quote them when they go into the file.  There are also better ways to iterate.

Comment: From http://mandrivausers.org/index.php?/topic/21998-reading-a-text-file-line-by-line-with-bash/ an alternate iterator is `cat FILE | while read line; do 
    echo $line # or whaterver you want to do with the $line variable ;
done`

Comment: Yes. That works. You may want to update your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close with the GNU Parallel version; only -n1 missing:

```
cat <xmls-file> | parallel -n1 --spreadstdin  xpath -p "//Path/to/node"
```

Comment: Yes. This is just what I wanted.